# Why is the p argument of choice parameter not working in python?

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability, dice

I am trying to assign probability to the 6 faces of dice with `choice()` of numpy library but whenever I run the program, it's showing me an error that `p` is not an argument of `choice()`. How to resolve this or is there any other method to assign probability to 6 faces without using numpy library.

[image]

Error that I'm getting:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [40], in <cell line: 5>()
      3 throws=100
      4 lis=[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1]
----> 5 probs(throws, lis)
      6 while(total<200):
      7     if dice==1 or dice==2:

Input In [39], in probs(throws, lis)
      1 def probs(throws, lis):
      2     dice=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
----> 3     x=random.choice(dice, throws, p =lis)

TypeError: choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'p'
```

Comment: Please post your code instead of a link to an image. Do you also use the `random` module?

Comment: your using the build-in random.choice, not numpy.random.choice

Answer (score 0):

Importing `random` will not get you the numpy module but the Python [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module.

`random.choice` only accepts a sequence as argument.

Your import should be as follows:

```py
from numpy import random

def probs(throws, lis):
    dice=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    x = random.choice(dice, throws, p=lis)
```

Now you are using `choice` from numpy as expected.